# How to use a WHERE statement in Postgres with an array of OR combinations?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure how to phrase this question, but the premise is I have a table where the primary key is defined by two columns: `row` and `col`. I also want to query for many individual columns, which is where my problem comes into play.

If I had a simple column named `id`, I would be able to do a clause such as `WHERE id=ANY($1)` where `$1` is an array of integers. However, with a primary key consisting of two columns, I wouldn't be able to the same.

`WHERE row=ANY($1) AND col=ANY($2)` gives me a region of what I want, but not the exact set of tuples that I need. Right now I'm generating a template query string with many conditions, such as:

```
WHERE row=$1 AND col=$2 OR
      row=$3 AND col=$4 OR ...
```

How can I avoid generating this "query template"? I don't think this is a very elegant solution, but it's the solution I have right now. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you do `WHERE ARRAY[row,col] = ANY($1)` where `$1` is an array of arrays of integers?

Comment: Is that a thing? If so, I'm gonna try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where (row,col) = any(array[(1,2),(3,4)])
```

or

```
where (row,col) in ((1,2),(3,4))
```

Comment: Thanks, was having a rough time with the syntax. I've used Postgres quite a bit, but not enough to know the ins and outs.